# Positive elements below projections

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $a$ be a positive element in $A$, where $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra. Let $p\in A$ a projection and suppose $a\leq p$.

Is it true that $ap=pa$? If yes, shouldn't we have $ap=pa=a$, since $(1-p)a(1-p)=0$?

Comment: What does $a \le p$ mean in a $C^\ast$ algebra?

Comment: $p-a$ positive i.e. there is $x\in A$ such that $p-a=xx^*$.

Comment: Thanks.  Just wiki'ed up  as well, but I like your definition better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like you said, $a$ lies in the corner $pAp$, for which $p$ is the unit.

Comment: and that's hereditary? That would solve it..

Comment: Corners are hereditary.

Comment: @Michael I think you would need separability to say that $pAp$ is hereditary